# spring data cassandra ImmutableMap exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Spring boot Cassandra starter 1.5.1 throws exceptions:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.AsyncFunction
```

and

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
```

when trying to create `CassandraClusterFactoryBean` object.

Is there a workaround for this?

A new Spring data - cassandra project from start.spring.io also throws a similar exception in its test run.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` means that those classes are not in your classpath, then you should add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>16.01</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using maven, just go to the this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava) and download the jar file and include that in your java classpath
Depending on how you are doing your project, this version of this dependency will change, just look for a compatible version for your spring-data version [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa)

Update:
You should use [guava 16.01 method](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0.1/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#sameThreadExecutor()), because in [guava 19 method](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#sameThreadExecutor()) the method is not valid anymore as the API said

```
@Deprecated
@GwtIncompatible(value="TODO")
public static ListeningExecutorService sameThreadExecutor()
Deprecated. Use directExecutor() if you only require an Executor and newDirectExecutorService() if you need a ListeningExecutorService. 
This method will be removed in August 2016.
```

According to the [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/3.1.3) in the compiled dependencies section, guava is 16.01

Comment: Spring data cassandra already brings in guava 19.0, but to check out it it works I have added 21.0 dep. That dint solve the problem, it still gives an exception with Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;
 at com.datastax.driver.core.PoolingOptions.<clinit>(PoolingOptions.java:146) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.1.3.jar:na]

Comment: See my update, you should use guava 16.01 as the compiled version point, any other version will give you conflicts